# why the if condition can't work in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i want to remove the vertical line。which is in the red circularity.
!

but when click the tab two.it showing like this:

[image]

The Following Code is not Working

```
   if($('#videotabs1').show()){
    $('.vtab2').css('border-right', 'none');
}
```

when the videotabs1 show. the `.vtab2` border is  not removed.

Comment: Can you post some HTML and CSS

Comment: Couldn't see that code you posted in the actual page - it looks correct, so add it wrapped with `$(document).ready(...)` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`show` returns the jQuery instance on which it's called, which is always truthy, and so no matter what you'll go into the `if`'s body. You might want [`is(":visible")`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), if you're trying to check if it's visible...but the tab will probably always be visible. Perhaps `.hasClass("whatever")` where "whatever" is whatever class you use for "active" tabs in your UI.

...in fact, this probably could be handled at the CSS end without using JavaScript at all (er, not using it *specifically* for this). If you have an "inactive" class you use for your inactive tabs, I'd include the `border-right: none;` rule in that.

Comment: the css can't get i want. how to add a class to the inactive tabs? i have added a class to the active tabs.thank you

Comment: if you use border-right: none; to the "inactive" class, when the tab2 is actived. there will be no border left.because tab1 border right is tab2 border left. i want the tab2 also has border.expect bord-bottom